# sed replace fails to replace string in if there's a square bracket

Tags: sed

My result variable contains the following:

```
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=888
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=888
```

I want to replace the entire lines and I'm using sed. The replace seems to work okay fir first iteration but not second one. However, when I print the values, it shows that the new value is correctly updated.

```
echo "$result" |
   while IFS= read -r line;
   do
      newValue=""
      for ii in $line
      do
         if [[ "$ii" != *"unlock_time"* ]]; then
            newValue="$newValue $ii"
         fi
      done
      newValue="$newValue unlock_time=900"
      sed -i "s/$line/$newValue/g" $password_auth
      echo " Line    : [ $line ]"
      echo "newValue : [ $newValue ]"
   done
```

The output shows this:

```
 Line    : [  auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=900 ]
newValue : [  auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=900 ]
 Line    : [ auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=888 ]
newValue : [  auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=900 ]
```

Here when it is displaying I see that the correct value is present in the variables and all the prints take place after sed command and I see no errors before prints in output.

But when I check the file, I see the second instance of unlock_time is still 888 instead of 900.

Note: I cannot globally replace unlock_time which is why I'm storing the lines that need updating in result.

Is there anything that is overlooked in the loop?

Update:
I've tried running the sed commands on command line:

```
sed -i "s/auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=900/auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=999/g" temp  <-- This works
sed -i "s/auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=9/auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=900/g" temp   <-- This doesn't update file but doesn't throw an error either
```

The command works on command line when I put escape characters around [default=die]. But how do I do it if I'm doing it through script?

Comment: If you want to match `[` or `]` in the LHS of a substitution command, they must be quoted i.e. `[` must be altered to `\[` or `[[]` so that `[` is not treated as a metacharacter for a [bracket expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions).

Comment: Yes, but in my case I'm reading the values from a file so I'll not know before hand if there's a bracket.

Comment: are you doing this with bash?

Comment: yes I am doing it via bash script...

Comment: If you want quote the `[` and `]` characters in a variable, use sed to make a new variable e.g. `newvar=$(<<<"$oldvar" sed 's/[].*[]/\\&/g')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a constant. The regexp matching through layers of quoting is getting in the way. Here's a simpler perl method (wrapped in bash for demo purposes):

```
#!/bin/bash

result="auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=888
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=888 unlock_time=888"

# create a file to play with
echo "$result" > testfile

echo "$result" | perl -i -pe '
    BEGIN { @find = <STDIN> }
    for $str (@find) {
        s/(\bunlock_time)=\d+/$1=900/ if $_ eq $str;
    }
' testfile

# check the result
cat testfile
```

- `-i` does inplace editing like sed
- `-p` wraps a while loop to read each line so an explicit one isn't needed and prints out the line after possible modification (a bit like sed)
- the `BEGIN` section initialises the array of strings to look for (from result)
- for each line of testfile (`$_`), `for` compares it against all the strings, and `if` there is a literal match (`eq`), does a regexp search&replace on the unlock_time parameter

Comment: Thanks for that. I've tried running that script...

Result variable:
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=990   unlock_time=900
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=990

Output:
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=990   unlock_time=900
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=990
The output is same as input...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? If you input 900 and change it to 900, the output will be 900