# Why can't sed find line in changelog

Tags: bash, shell, changelog

I am experimenting with bash scripting and wanted to write a function that can add a new changelog item when you run a certain command.

Give a changelog, the user runs `.changelog.sh` and a new changelog item is appended to the changelog after the line `## [Unreleased]`. Below is my code.

```
new_changelog_item()
{   
    while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "## [Unreleased]"* ]]; then
        echo $line
        echo "LINE FOUND IN" CHANGELOG.md
        sed -i "" "s/$line/## [Unreleased]\n## [$version] - $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')\n### Added\n - ADD CHANGE HERE!\n/g" CHANGELOG.md
        return
    fi

    done < CHANGELOG.md
}
```

The odd thing is, when I add a line below, let's say `<!--TESTING-->` and look for that line instead of `## [Unreleased]` the above code works accordingly IF there is a new line after the `TESTING` line. If I leave a new line after `## [Unreleased]` it still does not work.

I'm assuming my code can't find it because of the `[]`. If I remove those and add a new line it works. Is there a way around this where I can make it find the string even if it contains `[]`? This would be ideal as I am following the [Keep a Changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.0.0/) format.

Comment: Don't modify a file while you're reading from it.

Comment: @Barmar is it better to create a new file from scratch them delete the original one?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't modify the file you're reading from. `sed -i` creates a new file and renames it to the original filename.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143551/sed-replace-fails-to-replace-string-in-if-theres-a-square-bracket).

The `sed` replace wasn't working properly because the line was being evaluated as a [bracket expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) rather than as part of the string. To get around this, I ended up creating this variable before the replacement:

```
newvar=$(<<<"$line" sed 's/[].*[]/\\&/g')
```

Then instead of using `$line` in the `sed` statement I used `$newvar`. The code works correctly now.